# Click function with addClass not working in dynamic html()

Tags: jquery, html, click, addclass

The click function is not working in a dynamic added html. The class is tested in the new element as true but it ignores the click function for that class - although it is working fine in other elements.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// The added html element + addClass
$('#sendResultMsg').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="closeButt">Close</a>');
$('#sendResultMsg').find('#closeButt').addClass('closeButton');

// just for testing this alert confirms hasClass as true
alert($('#closeButt').hasClass('closeButton'));
```

the '#sendresult' is a  element in page and the html appears fine with the 'Close' link but when clicked nothing happens. The click function assigned to the class works fine in 2 other elements in page and its like this:

```
$('.toggleContactBox, .closeButton).on('click',function () {
  cntBox = $('#contactBox');
  cntBoxPos = cntBox.css('right');
  if (cntBoxPos <= '-550px') {
    cntBox.animate({ right: '0px' }, 200);
  } else {
    cntBox.animate({ right: '-550px' }, 200);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inorder to bind the event to dynamically added elements using `.on` you have to delegate the event to a higher element that is present in the DOM [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

try

```
$(document).on('click','.toggleContactBox, .closeButton',function () {
  cntBox = $('#contactBox');
  cntBoxPos = cntBox.css('right');
  if (cntBoxPos <= '-550px') {
    cntBox.animate({ right: '0px' }, 200);
  } else {
    cntBox.animate({ right: '-550px' }, 200);
  }
});
```

Comment: No need to bind event on `document` as `#sendResultMsg` is already present in DOM.

Comment: i was just making my point its up to the original poster how he uses it

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
$('.toggleContactBox, .closeButton).on('click',function () {
```

**With**

```
$('.toggleContactBox, .closeButton').on('click',function () {
```

You forgotten `'` when you used class selector.

Comment: How do you know that `.closeButton` is inside `.toggleContactBox`?

Comment: I missed the closing comma in the post but its there in code. These are two different classes that perform the same click function that's why wh they are comma separated. Anyway dakait gave me a solution that works. I'll try to understand why? and whats different from my approach... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$('#sendResultMsg').on('click', '.toggleContactBox, .closeButton', function () {
    ...
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

`If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.`

`When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'on' use live,it will work